# Keep getting “tsc.exe” exited with code 1 in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am getting this marvelous error "tsc.exe exited with code 1" for some hours now. I have the last Type Script, i installed any updates that i could found. I get it when i use the "Bootstrap CSS" package. Any idea?